# jQuery : Show up a jqPlot chart with a button

Tags: jquery, button, jqplot

I want to make an AJAX query then show up a jqPlot graph when I click on a "Get" button.

```
<script>
$("button").click(function(){
    var test = null;
    $.get("requete_graph.php", {
         id: param1,
         datemin: param2,
         datemax: param3
    }, function(data,status){
        test = data;
    }, "json");
    return test;
}); 

// Graph part
var blablabla = [[3,7,9,1,4,6,8,2,5]];
$(document).ready(function(){
    var plot1 = $.jqplot ('chartdiv', blablabla);
});
</script>
```

With this code, the graph shows up when the page is fully loaded.

---

```
<script>
$("button").click(function(){
    var test = null;
    $.get("requete_graph.php", {
         id: param1,
         datemin: param2,
         datemax: param3
    }, function(data,status){
        test = data;
    }, "json");
    return test;

    // Graph part
    var blablabla = [[3,7,9,1,4,6,8,2,5]];
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var plot1 = $.jqplot ('chartdiv', blablabla);
    });
}); 
</script>
```

With this, the graph never shows (even when I click on the button).

---

I want to use `$.jqplot` with the result of `$.get` (I just made the `blablabla` value to test the behaviour). What I want is to make an AJAX request then show a graph when I click on a "Get" button.
I'm just not sure on the jQuery syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Just put already prepared graph into invisible `div` and make it visible on button click.

Or you can do following:

```
var blablabla = [[3,7,9,1,4,6,8,2,5]];
$(document).ready(function(){
    var plot1 = $.jqplot ('chartdiv', blablabla);

    $("button").click(function(){
        var test = null;
        $.get("requete_graph.php", {
             id: param1,
             datemin: param2,
             datemax: param3
        }, function(data,status){
            test = data;
        }, "json");
        return test;
    }); 

});
```

In this case you will bind a click event when page is fully loaded.

Comment: Well, in the future, I want to use the `test` value. I just made a `blablabla` value to test the graph.
I know I have some more work to do to "transform" the JSON string because jqPlot can't interpret it like this.

So, I don't want to "bind a click event when page is fully loaded" and I don't want to "already prepared" it because some input values can be changed on the page.

Comment: Well, if you want reaction on button click, you WILL HAVE TO bind a click event, don't you? And when you put it in front of `$(document).ready()` , it fires up on literally nothing, `cause button is simply not there yet.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand... I want to use `$.jqplot` with the result of `$.get`. I don't care if a graph doesn't show up when the page is loading. All I want to do is make an AJAX request then show a graph when I click on a "Get" button.

Comment: Yes, and to achieve it you SHOULD execute `$("button").click()` function at some point, aren't you? To tell browser, that on button's click event it should do whatever you wrote inside this function. And you should NOT execute it BEFORE button is inserted into DOM, hence - put it into `document.ready` function.